# How to get a loop value in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, foxpro

```
FOR I = 1 TO 10
    tRESNUM = ALLTRIM(STR(I))
    tRESCAS = 'tRESCAS'+tRESNUM         

    &tRESCAS = 0.00

ENDFOR
```

I am converting this fox-pro code to MySQL Stored Procedure.

In Foxpro tRESCAS = 'tRESCAS'+tRESNUM gives tRESCAS1, tRESCAS2,..
and &tRESCAS gives the value which is tRESCAS1 or tRESCAS1 or ... something else.

For example

```
if I =1 =>

FOR I = 1 TO 10
        tRESNUM = ALLTRIM(STR(1))
        tRESCAS = 'tRESCAS'+1       

        tRESCAS1 = 0.00         
ENDFOR

If I =2 =>

FOR I = 1 TO 10
        tRESNUM = ALLTRIM(STR(2))
        tRESCAS = 'tRESCAS'+2       

        tRESCAS2 = 0.00         
ENDFOR
```

&tRESCAS Automatically take the tRESCAS value tRESCAS1 or tRESCAS2 like this.

In Stored Procedure How Can i get this type of Value?. (is any Special variable in stored procedure like & this?)

Is this details enough?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this procedure -

```
PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN

  DECLARE tRESCAS VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS t;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t(num INT, column1 VARCHAR(255));

  WHILE i < 10 DO
    INSERT INTO t VALUES(i, CONCAT('tRESCAS', i));
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  -- Try to get fifth value
  SELECT column1 FROM t WHERE num = 5;

END
```

All values are stored into temporary table.

Execute the procedure:

```
CALL procedure1;
+----------+
| column1  |
+----------+
| tRESCAS5 |
+----------+
```